# How does one disable keyboard control of a JSpinner via the arrow keys?

Tags: java, swing, input, clojure, key-bindings

This is a Clojure question regarding Java Swing, so people from either camp may be able to help me out.

I'm working on a hydrological data visualization program for my job and I've been having the darnedest time trying to figure this one out.

My application is based on displaying graphical precipitation information. Typical use involves tasks like displaying 24 hours' worth of rainfall data mapped over the southeastern US, with the internal state of the program keeping track of the end-time and number of hours over which to accumulate rainfall.

The main user interface consists of a main drawing pane, a couple of spinners, and a status bar (as seen below). The spinners and their labels are contained in their own JPanel, but the JTextField and JPanel containing the drawing-pane are top-level in the contentPane

[image: View of main interface]

The keybindings are defined in a format as seen below:

```
"control S" {:type :function
            :config :configure-shapefiles}
"control Z" {:type :function
             :config :configure-zooms}
"NUMPAD0" {:type :function
          :config :toggle-grids-on}
"VK_DOWN" {:type :function
          :config :prev-day}
"VK_UP" {:type :function
         :config :next-day}
"VK_RIGHT" {:type :function
           :config :next-hour}
"VK_LEFT" {:type :function
           :config :prev-hour}}
```

This configuration map is transformed into keybindings for the JFrame's content pane as follows:

```
(defn- set-keystroke-shortcuts
  []
  (let [inputmap (.getInputMap (.getContentPane frame) JComponent/WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
        actionmap (.getActionMap (.getContentPane frame))
        config (merge (read-clj "config/keybindings/site.clj")
                  (if (.exists (File. "config/keybindings/user.clj"))
                    (if-let [my-config ((read-clj "config/keybindings/user.clj") me)]
                       my-config {})))]
    (doseq [[k {shortcut-type :type shortcut-info :config}] config
           :let [sym-name (str (gensym))
                 fun (case shortcut-type
                          :plot #(process-display-config shortcut-info)
                          :function (dealias-keystroke-config-keyword shortcut-info)
                          #{})]]

      (.put inputmap (KeyStroke/getKeyStroke k) sym-name)
      (.put actionmap sym-name (action fun)))))
```

To save space, I haven't included the code for dealias-keystroke-config-keyword and process-display-config. I will clarify that the :next-day, :prev-day, :next-hour, and :prev-hour keywords result in shifting the end-hour of the analysis by 24, -24, 1, and -1 hours respectively.

The issue I'm running into is that my attempts to bind these commands to the arrow keys aren't working. Whenever I bind them to other, non-arrow keys, everything works as planned. But when I try to bind them to the arrow keys, the "X:" spinner intercepts the key event and it won't fire...instead, UP and DOWN just result in the X spinner moving up and down.

If I disable the spinners, the keybindings work, but that defeats the purpose of the spinners. If I disable the spinners, hit the arrow keys, and then re-enable them, then it works, but I have to manually disable them via the REPL, then go back to the application window, hit the arrow keys, then reenable them in my REPL. Not a solution.

Trying to remove the keybindings from the spinners doesn't yield much -- it says there are no keybindings!

```
(.allKeys (.getInputMap x-panes-spinner)) => nil
```

Going through the children of the spinners isn't helpful either in this regard:

```
(doseq [comp (.getComponents x-panes-spinner)
        k (.allKeys (.getInputMap comp))]
   (prn [(.getName comp) (.getKeyCode k)]))

  => ["Spinner.nextButton" 32]
  => ["Spinner.nextButton" 32]
  => ["Spinner.nextButton" 10]
  => ["Spinner.nextButton" 10]
  => ["Spinner.previousButton" 32]
  => ["Spinner.previousButton" 32]
  => ["Spinner.previousButton" 10]
  => ["Spinner.previousButton" 10]
```

32 and 10 correspond to the spacebar and enter keys, so that doesn't help me.

I'm fairly confident I could add a MouseListener to enable/disable the spinners only when they're entered, but I'd  rather just stop them from reacting to the arrow pad events rather than having them dynamically enable and disable.

Any ideas, StackOverflow? I'd at a loss on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Trying to remove the keybindings from the spinners doesn't yield much -- it says there are no keybindings!

Check out [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of all the bindings for each Swing component.

The following will then disable the bindings for the spinner:

```
InputMap im = spinner.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "DOWN"), "none");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "UP"), "none");
```

Comment: This seems to work great! I'm still having issues with SOMETHING intercepting left and right keystroke events, but this is pointing me in the right direction. Thank you!